# Nestjs compilation gives Expression expected error?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, nestjs

on running a nestjs project with the version of typescript, nestjs and npm listed below I am getting following errors.

```
nest start --watch
```

its gives this error

```
node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:71:43 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

71             | ReadonlyArray<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                             ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:71:66 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

71             | ReadonlyArray<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                                                    ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:71:67 - error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

71             | ReadonlyArray<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                                                     ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:72:13 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

72             | Iterable<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:72:38 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

72             | Iterable<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:72:53 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

72             | Iterable<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                                       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:72:61 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

72             | Iterable<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                                               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:72:62 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

72             | Iterable<readonly [name: string, value: string]>
                                                                ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:73:13 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

73             | { readonly [name: string]: string }
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:73:31 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

73             | { readonly [name: string]: string }
                                 ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:73:39 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

73             | { readonly [name: string]: string }
                                         ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:73:40 - error TS1136: Property assignment expected.

73             | { readonly [name: string]: string }
                                          ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:75:5 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

75     );
       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:77:16 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

77     append(name: string, value: string): void;
                  ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:77:31 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

77     append(name: string, value: string): void;
                                 ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:77:40 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

77     append(name: string, value: string): void;
                                          ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:77:46 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

77     append(name: string, value: string): void;
                                                ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:78:16 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

78     delete(name: string): void;
                  ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:78:24 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

78     delete(name: string): void;
                          ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:78:25 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

78     delete(name: string): void;
                           ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:78:31 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

78     delete(name: string): void;
                                 ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:79:13 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

79     get(name: string): string | null;
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:79:22 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

79     get(name: string): string | null;
                        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:80:16 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

80     getAll(name: string): string[];
                  ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:80:25 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

80     getAll(name: string): string[];
                           ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:80:34 - error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.

80     getAll(name: string): string[];
  

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:81:13 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

81     has(name: string): boolean;
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:81:22 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

81     has(name: string): boolean;
                        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:82:13 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

82     set(name: string, value: string): void;
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:82:28 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

82     set(name: string, value: string): void;
                              ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:82:37 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

82     set(name: string, value: string): void;
                                       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:82:43 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

82     set(name: string, value: string): void;
                                             ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:83:11 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

83     sort(): void;
             ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:83:17 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

83     sort(): void;
                   ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:85:11 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

85     keys(): IterableIterator<string>;
             ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:85:37 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

85     keys(): IterableIterator<string>;
                                       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:86:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

86     values(): IterableIterator<string>;
               ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:86:39 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

86     values(): IterableIterator<string>;
                                         ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:87:14 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

87     entries(): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:87:38 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

87     entries(): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:87:53 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

87     entries(): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                                       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:87:63 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

87     entries(): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                                                 ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:88:22 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

88     forEach<THIS_ARG = void>(
                        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:88:28 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

88     forEach<THIS_ARG = void>(
                              ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:89:17 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

89         callback: (this: THIS_ARG, value: string, name: string, searchParams: this) => void,
                   ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:89:92 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

89         callback: (this: THIS_ARG, value: string, name: string, searchParams: this) => void,
                                                                                              ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:90:17 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

90         thisArg?: THIS_ARG,
                   ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:91:5 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

91     ): void;
       ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:91:6 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

91     ): void;
        ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:91:12 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

91     ): void;
              ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:93:34 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

93     readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: 'URLSearchParams';
                                    ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:94:24 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

94     [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                          ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:94:48 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

94     [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                                  ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:94:63 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

94     [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                                                 ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:94:73 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

94     [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[name: string, value: string]>;
                                                                           ~

node_modules/@types/whatwg-url/index.d.ts:95:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

95 }
   ~
```

I have tried reinstalling node several times and use different versions of nodes.
Operating system : Windows 11

typescript version : Version 3.9.10

nestjs version : 7.0.0

node version : v10.24.1

npm version : 6.14.12

Comment: Whoa, Node 10? That's been deprecated for a while now hasn't it? Node 18 is current and about to be LTS

Comment: add this flag into your tsconfig: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#skipLibCheck

Comment: @MicaelLevi can you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: add `"skipLibCheck": true` to your `tsconfig.json` file under `compilerOptions`